# How to initiate a file download using a crossrider request?

Tags: crossrider

I'm storing custom images on our servers.  I'd like to have the user download the images using our plugin.  When I send the request to the server I can see that it is started correctly but the file save dialog never comes up.

Does anyone know how to do this or can point me to an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, for security reasons, extensions created on Crossrider or otherwise do not provide functionality to access/save to the local files system. There are various workaround suggestions on various Stack Overflow threads (e.g. [Chrome extension: How to save a file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153979/chrome-extension-how-to-save-a-file-on-disk)) that may work on certain browsers. Whilst Crossrider does not support or guarantee that they will work, you can of course try to make them work in your Crossrider extension.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]