# Is there a way to save files directly to your local hard drive through a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to know how to make a function(s) that directly creates, and can modify or edit files on your disk from the chrome extension without downloading it.
Something like

```
function savefile(file) {
// function to save file
}
```

I don't understand how to do this inside a chrome extension and if it is even possible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a Chrome extension save many files to a user-specified directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802032/how-can-a-chrome-extension-save-many-files-to-a-user-specified-directory)

Comment: Check [Chrome extension: How to save a file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153979/chrome-extension-how-to-save-a-file-on-disk)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension: How to save a file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153979/chrome-extension-how-to-save-a-file-on-disk)

Comment: Extensions can only download files. [Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) can write files directly but only on ChromeOS. There's an old HTML5 FileSystem API but it's only for internal virtualized files so not usually helpful. The closest thing is the new upcoming [Native File System API](https://web.dev/native-file-system/) but again it's not usable yet.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extension - no. Chrome apps also - no. Chrome apps were possible some time ago. Now you can build web application with files api, read more here:

https://developer.chrome.com/articles/file-system-access/

You can check current support by browsers (i just picked most common API calls related to this):

- https://caniuse.com/?search=showDirectoryPicker
- https://caniuse.com/?search=showSaveFilePicker
- https://caniuse.com/?search=getAsFileSystemHandle

At this moment (2023-09-21) this API seems to be usable on Chrome, Edge and Opera only.

> The File System Access API allows web apps to read or save changes directly to files and folders on the user's device.

> The File System Access API (formerly known as Native File System API and prior to that it was called Writeable Files API) enables developers to build powerful web apps that interact with files on the user's local device, such as IDEs, photo and video editors, text editors, and more. After a user grants a web app access, this API allows them to read or save changes directly to files and folders on the user's device. Beyond reading and writing files, the File System Access API provides the ability to open a directory and enumerate its contents.