# Read and write files in a folder using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've searched throught the chrome extension documentations and I'm not able to found the info I need. I would to make an extension who need to read files from a specific folder that I want to create when the extension is installed. Is possible with the chrome provided APIs to write and read data from a specific folder on the users machine?
For example if I want to write a json file on the user pc, will this be possible, or there is any kind of restriction about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer, if you haven't already:

[Chrome extension: How to save a file on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153979/chrome-extension-how-to-save-a-file-on-disk)

What are the file formats of the files you want to read though? For anything that is JSON-able, you can read/write json using `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()` and `chrome.storage.local.get` and `chrome.storage.local.set` (or, change "local" for "sync" if you want it to be synched across devices that I used is signed in on). I assume you know this, anyway though

Comment: I don't want to use storage api due to the storage size limitation. I want to save standalone .json files and be able to have a dedicated folder created by the extension that can work as an archive. the download api will give me the ability to save files, but for .json, I'm using a js db that create this kind of files and I'm not sure if I can create them directly on the pc

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I need to look into this more myself, since I'm currently working on a couple of extensions. It seems you definitely know more about me about the capabilities though...so I'm not much help lol